# The number of images of the point is.?

Tags: mathematics

Two plane mirrors facing each other are arranged at $60^o$ to each other. A point is located on the angle bisector. How many images of the point are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a direct formula. If $360/A$ is even then number of images formed  = $(360/A) - 1$ irrespective of it's position.
Which in this case is 5.

To know more visit https://physicswithpradeep.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/ray-optics.pdf.

Comment: but answer is 6

Comment: @Psuresh, and how?

Comment: @Psuresh which book are you following?

Comment: its csir exam question

Comment: @Psuresh Sometimes in such number of image problem there is an ambiguity in which the problem designer expects us to count number of images along with the original object. Just go through the question again and check if they've asked for total objects visible. I've faced these types of problems in JEE paper.